# Difference between Ordering and Order?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, order-theory

I am confused by the two terms *order* and *ordering*. I am learning on Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et all. The context is monomial orderings and Gröbner basis on polynomial rings.

**How are the terms *ordering* and *order* different? Are they synonyms?**

Comment: I have never seen them mean different things, but I can't a priori say that the authors of your book use them interchangably.

Comment: Can you quote the context in the book where these terms are used?

Comment: @lhf monomial orderings and Gröbner basis on polynomial rings.

Comment: Coincidence?  The question below this is "Second Order Derivative Test".

Answer (score 3):

A (total) *order* is a binary relation in a set $S$ that is reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive and is defined for all pairs of elements.

An *ordering* is a way to put elements in *order*. This may be used as a synonym for *enumeration*, that is, an explicit bijection $\mathbb N \to S$.

For instance, there are several orderings for $\mathbb Q$.

In the context of the book, there are several orderings for the set of monomials in several variables. For instance, you can give priority to $x_1$ or to $x_n$.

On the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) says that *ordering* is the same as *total order*.

Answer (score 1):

Order: a binary relation among elements of a set which is: reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric.
Ordering: if every empty subset of a set has a minimum. In general, this is the difference.

Comment: I have it, but is in italian...